# Handle asynchronous notifications in a specific order

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, servlets, project-reactor

I'm using a javax.servlet to get asynchronous notifications about the state of a payment done by a user.
Every notification contains information that needs to be updated in the database, for example - user details, amount paid, payment id, payment state, etc...

For example, a set of notification for one payment with id=1:

```
{user_msisdn='',      amount_paid=0.00, payment_id = 1, payment_state=NEW}
{user_msisdn=0012345, amount_paid=0.00, payment_id = 1, payment_state=PENDING}
{user_msisdn=0012345, amount_paid=2.00, payment_id = 1, payment_state=COMPLETED}
```

Even though the notifications are asynchronouse, the database updates **must be in order**, so when i update my payment table, the payment entry with id = 1 must be first updated to state '*NEW*', then to '*PENDING*', then to '*COMPLETED*'.
Some other internal actions are done in my code for each payment_state, so this is not only about **transaction management.**

My problem is that sometimes these notifications arrive in a milliseconds interval, and in this case when the required actions done e.g for 'NEW' notification are not yet completed, and then '*PENDING*' arrives, the database might be updated first with the '*PENDING*' state and then overridden with '*NEW*'...

I am looking for a solution which will handle notifications for different payment ids concurrently but notifications with the same payment id sequentially in the same order they were received.

- The current implementation is using an Aspect around the notification handling method, which prevents calls for the same payment_id to be executed at the same time. but im looking for a better solution
- I thought about using **ActiveMQ**, but then i would have to create queue / topic for each payment_id, which would be way too much.
- I was also reading a bit about **Spring Reactor**, but i'm not sure i can create a dispatcher for every payment_id dynamically
- Maybe use some lock on the payment_id which will prevent other notifications with the same payment_id from being handled until finished?
- Any other ideas?

Thanks you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at the producer-consumer concept

[wiki/Producer–consumer_problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem)

[producer-consumer-pattern](https://dzone.com/articles/producer-consumer-pattern)

If you have to handle the events in a specific order, you should think about a consumer, which is able to sort/ignore incoming events, if your order requirement will not fit.

If you find a broken order like PENDING is before NEW, you add PENDING to the end of the queue again. The next will be NEW, this you can execute. The next incoming is COMPLETED, but because PENDING was not called yet, you put COMPLETE also to the end of the queue and the order is valid.

Sure you have to take care about missing event. Otherwise you have Events which are always added again for no reason, but this is a special error handling logic.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! 
I also thought about using queues but then i would have to create a queue for every payment_id since i only care about the order of notifications for the same payment_id. 
It could be hundreds of queues per second, which will no longer be used after this payment is processed since every payment_id is unique, so then i would need to discard them somehow.
Isnt it a bit of an overhead?